# How to use DATEDIFF function with Eloquent?

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

Here is my code for selecting reservations:

```php
Reservation::select(array(
    'obj_id', 
    'name', 
    'surname',
    'date_from',
    'date_to', 
    'days',
    'status',
    'slug',
    'payable'
));
```

My question is how to change 'days' to get real diff between `date_from` and `date_to`? I don't have 'days' column in the database, I just want to count them in the SQL query.

In pure SQL should be something like that:

```sql
SELECT DATEDIFF('date_from, date_to) AS Days FROM RESERVATIONS;
```

How can I do that using Eloquent?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use [DB::raw](http://laravel.com/docs/queries#raw-expressions) for this.

```
Reservation::select(array(
            'obj_id', 'name', 'surname',
            'date_from', 'date_to', 
            'days',
            'status', 'slug', 'payable', 
            DB::raw("DATEDIFF(date_from,date_to)AS Days"))
))
```

Comment: Thank you Abishek! This is proper solution.